# Is there a way to find out which user renamed a branch in Git?

Tags: git

Is it possible to find out which user renamed a branch in Git? We are using Kiln, but I am unable to find anything relating to this. Many Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586534/how-to-manage-branches-with-kiln-using-git) might be useful. Not adressing branch *renaming* per se, but useful if you have not already stumbled upon it.

Comment: Pure git doesn't have a concept of users (other than the basically unverified "author" and "commiter" fields). So you'd need something like Github, GitLab or Bitbucket to have a chance of collecting this kind of information (and I don't know if any of those track this).